# Cannot debug Java application with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging, vert.x

I have a Java (Vert.x) application on my machine that I am trying to attach Eclipse to for debugging.

I usually start the Java application in my console like so:

```
java -jar build/libs/my-app.jar
```

Upon reading about debugging, I am attempting to start the app as follows:

```
java -jar build/libs/my-app.jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transort:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

The app seems to start up in the console fine when I run this.

I then go into Eclipse, and try to connect to the app via debugging via `Run` -> `Debug Configurations`. This is what my debug configuration looks like:

[image: my-app debugging]

When I click debug, I get an error box that pops up and says that the connection is refused (I covered the name of my real app). See below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get remote debugging to connect to my app with Eclipse?

Comment: Check whether java opened port using `netstat`, and make sure you have put correct hostname into `Host` input box

Comment: Also, check firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: also make sure your Eclipse Network Proxy Configuration is set to bypass the proxy for 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my reading of this [JDWP documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation), your -Xrunjdwp option is incorrect:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transort:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

should be

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

If your system has multiple IP addresses, there could be some confusion about which IPs the agent is listening for connections on.  You could force a specific address; e.g.

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

and use the matching IP and port in the Eclipse debug connection parameters.

---

AND ... as Dave Thompson spotted ... all JVM options must be placed **before** the `-jar` argument.  (Anything after the `-jar name.jar` will be treated as command line arguments for your application.)

Comment: And it must be _before_ the `-jar jarfile` option; anything after `-jar jarfile` or `mainclassname` is used as argument(s) _to the Java application_.

Comment: Good catch!  Updated.